# Python check that string of emails list (e.g. "email1, email2, email3,...") is valid

Tags: python, string, validation, email, dns

I have a string of emails separated by comma and 1 space:

```
string_of_emails = "email1@company.com, email2@company.com, email3@company.com, ... , email999@company.com"
```

I want to run a validation test on that string that will make sure the string is really from the above format.

Meaning - check that EACH email is VALID (user@domain.com) + each email is separated by comma and 1 space + the last email shouldn't have a comma.

Comment: if an email doesnt have the required format, what is the output?

Comment: You will have to write some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the string to a list:

```
emails = string_of_emails .split(", ")
```

After that, you can either do your own regex check for each individual email, or use one of the many packages available to do this for you:
[Python Email Validator](https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator)

```
for mail in emails:
    # do your own regex check here
    # OR
    # Use the email validator like this
    v = validate_email(email) # function from the email validator
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share a rough idea...

```
import re
soe = "abc_123@123.com ,you@yahoo.com , we@gmail.co.uk, gmail.com, me@outlook.com ,"
soel = soe.split(',')

#first entry cannot have space
if soel[0].count(" ")!=0 :
    print("Error\t\t:: First entry cannot contain space!")
#then, all subsequent must start with and contain exactly one space, along with a valid email
for email in soel[1:]:
    if email.count(" ") > 1:
        print("Invalid entry\t::" + email, ":: too many spaces")
        continue
    #simple email regex (with a single space in front)
    match = re.search(r' ([\w\.-]+)@([\w\.-]+)', email)
    if match == None:
        print("Invalid entry\t::" + email + ":: make sure it follows the rule!")
    else:
        print("Valid entry\t::" + email)
```

or for more details,

```
import re
soe = " abc_123@123.com,you@yahoo.com , we@gmail.co.uk, gmail.com, me@outlook.com ,"
soel = soe.split(',')

end = len(soel)
if soel[-1].strip()=='':
    print("Error:: Comma near the end of string!")
    end -= 1
if soel[0].count(" ")>0:
    print("Error:: First entry cannot contain space!")
for email in soel[1:end]:
    if email.count(" ") != 1 :
        print("Error:: " + email + " :: too many spaces!")
        continue
    if not email.startswith(" "):
        print("Error:: " + email + " :: one space is needed after comma!")
        continue
    #simple email regex
    match = re.search(r'([\w\.-]+)@([\w\.-]+)', email)
    if match != None:
        print("Correct format: " + match.group())
```

Comment: Your solution is good, but there is a lot to consider when validating email addresses. The necessary regex patterns are often quite extensive, so I always tend to use packages that specialize in this task. For example, the default configuration of the tool I linked in my answer even checks if the top-level domain is valid. However, this requires an Internet connection, but this option can be disabled.